# Trying to toggle a Div on Click event of a TD tag, but facing issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, toggle

I am trying to toggle (increase and decrease height of )a DIV based on click event of a TD tag using jQuery. Please note I am new to jQuery.

```
<td id="ProductionTargetDEtd" class="collapsibleTdRelease" width="100%" onclick="javascript:toggleHeader();">
<table width="100%">
    // Some Html code here
</table>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<div id="ProductionTargetDEDiv" class="slidingDiv" style="">
  // Some Html code here
</div>
</td>
```

Now in the JSP script tag I am hiding the DIV by giving height = 0 as below :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).find("div#ProductionTargetDEDiv").each(function() {$(this).css({  overflow: "hidden", height: "0px" })});
</script>
});
```

Finally on click event of the TD id="ProductionTargetDEtd" we are calling below javascript method toggleHeader():

```
function toggleHeader(){
    $("td#ProductionTargetDEtd").removeAttr("onclick");

    $("td#ProductionTargetDEtd").toggle(function(){
            $("div#ProductionTargetDEDiv").animate({ height: 135}, 400);
        },function(){
            $("div#ProductionTargetDEDiv").animate({ height: 0 }, 400);
    });
}
```

Now what all this is supposed to do is, when i click on the TD tag, the DIV should slide down, and next click it should slide up. The above method is working fine, except for 1 anomalies :

1) On 1st click, nothing happens, only on 2nd time clicking and onwards the DIV slides down and up smoothly

Surprizingly, If i don't call the Javascript method toggleHeader() using inline javascript call

```
onclick="javascript:toggleHeader()"
```

and instead i put all the jQuery code in the  tag of the JSP, then this 1st click problem is solved.

Comment: Based on other stackoverflow link http://stackoverflow.com/a/10049798/1316967 i realized that because I am calling my jQuery code using inline javascript -> onclick="javascript:toggleHeader();"" therefore the click event is occuring twice and hence the issue
Now i added $("td#ProductionTargetDEtd").removeAttr("onclick"); in my jQuery code and it is working fine now.
Only issue being the slide is not working fr the 1st click. After that everything is working smooth

Answer (score 0):

why do u need trigger for ProductionTargetDEDiv click...remove that..

you are calling `td#ProductionTargetDEtd` click event twice.. one in your html

here

```
<td id="ProductionTargetDEtd" class="collapsibleTdRelease" width="100%" onclick="javascript:toggleHeader();">
```

and here

```
 $("td#ProductionTargetDEtd").click( //inside the toggleHeader function
```

so remove `$("td#ProductionTargetDEtd").click(` inside the `toggleHeader`  and that should solve your click function

final outcome... replace `toggleHeader` with this

```
function toggleHeader(){
  $("div#ProductionTargetDEDiv").toggle(function(){
        $(this).animate({ height: 135 }, 200);
    },function(){
        $(this).animate({ height: 0 }, 200);
  });
}
```

and it should work

Comment: Hi bipen, as I mentioned in my problem point no # 3, if i don't add that trigger for $("div#ProductionTargetDEDiv").click();  no toggle happens anymore. Only on adding this line, toggle is happening. This is with reference from this stackoverflow entry 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3036530/1316967

Comment: than that trigger for click, we are doing it in `ProductionTargetDEtd` element.. have you tried with above code

Comment: hi bipen, latest update : plz read my comments to my own question above. I followed your code above plus I added below line
    $("td#ProductionTargetDEtd").removeAttr("onclick");
In order to curb the occurence of duplicate Click events due to calling jQuery click toggle method from inline javascript code
    "onclick="javascript:toggleHeader();"
everything is resolved after this except the fact that nothing happens for the 1st click...After that everything happens v smoothly :) can u help this last bit.